# Precedence of UsePreviousAppDir and /DIR in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

There is `Setup` parameter `UsePreviousAppDir`, which sets default application app path of Inno Setup installer to previously used one. And there is command line switch `/DIR`, which allows user to set custom default app path.

So, my question is, in which order these two parameters are determining application path? If I specify both, which one will be used by installer in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/DIR` command-line switch overrides everything else (with exception of `/LOADINF`).

That's its purpose.